# Using boost preprocessor to stringize a tuple

Tags: c++, boost, boost-preprocessor

I am beginner in using boost preprocessor. I want to use this library to generate a name from a tuple, for example I have a tuple like this `(float, string, int, bool)` and I want to construct something like this `"Foo<float, string, int, bool>"`. I thought that it must be easy by using `BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE`, `BOOST_PP_CAT` and `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` but I unfortunately could not find a way to generate the string I wanted.

Please give me a suggestion about creating this string. `Foo` is a class name and tuple is generated automatically during preprocess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM` to get a comma-separated expansion of the tuple elements. You can then use `#__VA_ARGS__` to stringize the resulting list. [See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d313a588339c2f0):

```
#define STRINGIZE_ALL_I(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define STRINGIZE_ALL(...) STRINGIZE_ALL_I(__VA_ARGS__)

#define MAKE_STRING(tuple) STRINGIZE_ALL(Foo<BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM(tuple)>)

// "Foo<float, string, int, bool>"
MAKE_STRING((float, string, int, bool))
```

`STRINGIZE_ALL_I` exists for the same reason you have an extra layer in `STRINGIZE` and `CONCAT` - to evaluate macros before stringizing. In this case, you would get a string containing `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM((…))` if you neglected to have two layers.

Note that `STRINGIZE_ALL` is called with the argument list `Foo<float`, `string`, `int`, `bool>`. That's four arguments, not one.

---

If variadic macros are not available (e.g., C++98), you can take advantage of the fact that `"abc" "def"` will be turned into `"abcdef"` by the compiler. [See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/021273e09333ac29):

```
#define STRINGIZE_ALL_MACRO(s, state, x) state "," BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(x)

#define STRINGIZE_ALL(seq)      \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOLD_LEFT(     \
        STRINGIZE_ALL_MACRO,    \
        BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(seq)), \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(seq)  \
    )

#define MAKE_STRING(size, tuple) \
    STRINGIZE_ALL(               \
        BOOST_PP_TUPLE_TO_SEQ(   \
            size,                \
            (Foo<BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM(size, tuple)>) \
        )                        \
    )

// "Foo<float" "," "string" "," "int" "," "bool>"
MAKE_STRING(4, (float, string, int, bool))
```

For this version, your autogenerated tuple must generate a size as well. It's entirely possible to generate a tuple `(size, (elems))` that you can use with this macro.